# How can I retrieve Firebase user properties?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to retrieve *Firebase* user properties in *Analytics for Firebase*?

For example, Analytics has all user records. I want to retrieve a record about user information, such as country code, etc. using Analytics.

Is there any API available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase doesn't retain any PII (Personally Identifiable Information) about anyone using your app.  It aggregates information across users.  It doesn't associate specific user information from Firebase Authentication.

Also, there is no API for data it stores.  If you want access to raw data, you have to export it to BigQuery (but there will still not be PII in that export).