# How to get Firebase automatically collected user properties?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am hosting my web app on firebase and its clear that firebase knows where app is being browsed from, as i can see location data in firebase analytics. Fire-base automatically collects some user properties like country. Is there any method i can get this property value (country code or name) so i can curate app content accordingly?

I have found this line in firebase docs.
Analytics derives location data from users' IP addresses.

As google firebase doesn't disclose users IP addresses to developers. So its firebase duty to tell the users country to devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase derives information from the reported properties. This derived information is only available in the Firebase console (in the Analytics panel, and in other panels that build audiences based on analytics data).

There is no way to access the derived information in your own code, or to get it in the data exported to BigQuery. If you need similar information you will need to derive it yourself.

Also see:

- [How can I retrieve Firebase user properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719450/how-can-i-retrieve-firebase-user-properties)

Comment: Is there any method in firebase to get the county code or country name of visitor to show the data accordingly? And if not, can't you add this feature to firebase? . I know you are at some very high position in firebase.